# Include a string text next to number views of a video

Tags: php, wordpress

In my  project web, the YouTube videos are embedded showing at the foot of the video the number of views of the YouTube video, so I wrote the following code (see "**Code 2**" below). This code shows the number of views. Furthemore, I need the word "*views*" is located next to the number views (i.e 2,343 **views**). I tried to define a variable and then show its content using the `print` or `echo` function, the problem is that the word "***views***" does not appear next to the number. Below you can see my try (see "**Code 1**").

May you help me to show this word?

**Code 1**

```
 $viewtext = "views";
    return number_format($views, 0, '', '.');
    print '$viewtext';
```

**Code 2**

```
function youtube_view_count_shortcode($params) {
$videoID = $params['id'];
$json = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos? 
part=statistics&id=" . $videoID . 
"&key=AIzaSyAdIxrKb2xx7ylckO2uj3RShaKCP79Ipz0");
$jsonData = json_decode($json);
$views = $jsonData->items[0]->statistics->viewCount;
return number_format($views, 0, '', '.');
}
add_shortcode('youtube_view_count', 'youtube_view_count_shortcode');
```

Comment: Nothing is executed after `return`. That sends it back. Concatenate the values to the string.

Comment: @user3783243 I tried to put the following code below "return" but nothing happened. Why?  $viewtext = "views"; print '$viewtext';  Thanks

Comment: `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function,` http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php aka `code below "return"` will not be fired

Answer (score 0):

Add `$views = $views . " views";` to the end (before you `return` the views, but after finding the number).

Also keep  in mind that you should change the 's' at the end if there is 1 view.

Comment: @user5037898 when I wrote `$views = $views . " views"` just before `return` line, the word "views" is not added to the viewcount number. May it to be related with the shortcode created, when I add the shortcode into the post?, because I include the following one: `[youtube_view_count id="videoID"]` It is considering the line code `$views = $views . " views"`